# How can I set the private IP address of an Azure web role as static?

Tags: azure, azure-cloud-services, azure-virtual-network

I have a Azure cloud service containing several web roles, in an Azure virtual network. I want to set the roles' private ip addresses as static, so that the web roles can communicate over the network.  However, the private ip addresses change when the cloud service is updated. How can I set the private ip address as static so that it doesn't change with every deployment? I want to do the same thing I can with virtual machines:

[image]

Comment: __"I want to set the roles' private ip addresses as static, so that the web roles can communicate over the network."__ -- Can you expand a little bit on that? What kind of data you need to exchange? I'm guessing you're ruling out a shared key-value store or pub-sub like Redis cache or a queue system like Azure Storage Queues. But you're not stating the why.

Comment: __"How can I set the private ip address as static so that it doesn't change with every deployment?"__ -- Here's the problem with that. What if your deployment will have 5 more instances in 1 month (2 Web, 3 Worker)? Now, which IP is which?

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to have a static IP address for your roles or VMs you will have to use the Reserved IP addresses feature. A maximum of 20 reserved IP addresses are available per subscription. 
https://azure.microsoft.com/en-in/documentation/articles/virtual-networks-reserved-public-ip/

In powershell you can do this to create a new Reserved IP

```
$ReservedIP = New-AzureReservedIP -ReservedIPName "FirewallIP" -Label "WebAppFirewallIP" -Location "Japan West"
```

In Service config of a role  you can specify like this ,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ServiceConfiguration serviceName="ReservedIPSample" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ServiceHosting/2008/10/ServiceConfiguration" osFamily="4" osVersion="*" schemaVersion="2014-01.2.3">
  <Role name="WebRole1">
    <Instances count="1" />
    <ConfigurationSettings>
      <Setting name="Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Plugins.Diagnostics.ConnectionString" value="UseDevelopmentStorage=true" />
    </ConfigurationSettings>
  </Role>
  <NetworkConfiguration>
    <AddressAssignments>
      <ReservedIPs>
       <ReservedIP name="MyReservedIP"/>
      </ReservedIPs>
    </AddressAssignments>
  </NetworkConfiguration>
</ServiceConfiguration>
```

In general though, if you do not delete a deployment you will have the same IP address for a given cloud service.

Comment: Is this possible with private ip addresses though? I want to be able to do the same thing as I can with virtual machines (I've added a screenshot to my question)

Comment: within a vnet a static private ip can set for vms, cloud services etc. whereas reserved IP addresses are fixed for a particular cloud resource and they act as VIP. they are static but I believe they may not be private. I guess my answer might not really help your cause.

Comment: There's always `RoleEnvironment.CurrentRoleInstance.Role.Instances` if what you're looking for is the collection of all active instances or `Environment.MachineName` to grab hostname. You seem to be trying to associate state with your instances which is a bit fighting against the nature of the service (stateless).